# Find integer solutions of $x^2 -px +q=0$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Quick number theory question that I have just come across, was wondering if anyone could shed some light on it.

> So $p$ and $q$ are given to be prime numbers, and we are told that the equation $x^2 -px +q=0$ has two integer solutions.  How can might one find them?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean that if p = 3 and q = 2 that the solutions are 1 and 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the roots are two integers $a$ and $b$, then $p=a+b$ while $q=ab$. Since $q$ is prime, without loss of generality we may assume $a=\pm 1$. So suppose $a=1$, then $b=q$ and $p=q+1$ which forces $q=2,p=3$ (since both $p$ and $q$ are prime and differ by one).  <s>Similarly, if $a=-1$, we must have $p=2,q=3$</s>. No! When $a=-1,~b=-q$ and $p=-q-1<0$ cannot be prime, so there is no solution.

Comment: $x^2-2x+3$ has no real zeroes, let alone integer zeroes.

Comment: @CameronBuie wow, that's what I get for getting an answer out  in a rush.

Comment: If negative primes are allowed, then the $a=-1$ case implies $p=-3$ and $q=2$. I'm not sure if the OP is considering those, though.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the equation $x^2 - px + q$ has two integer solutions $a$ and $b$. Then $a + b = p$ and $ab = q$. Since $q$ is prime, we can assume $a = 1$, $b = q$. Therefore $q + 1 = p$ is also prime. The only possibility is $p = 3, q = 2$ and the solutions are 1 and 2. Similarly is $a = -1$, $b=-q$ and $p = 2, q = 3$.

Comment: We posted exactly the same solution, even with the same notation, and almost the same wording ^^.

Comment: Except I forgot the case $a = -1$... Silly me.

Comment: it happens. 15characters

Comment: It seems I was wrong after all :D

Answer (score 3):

Hint: by the [Rational Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) (or Factor Theorem) the roots must be factors of the prime $q$.